# Number of CPUs while using WebSphere Liberty for free in production

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

As we can read [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/websphere-application-server-everyone/) WebSphere Liberty is free for production use while heap size is at most 2GB. But there is no information about number of processors allowed to be used. I've done some googling, but found nothing. Also I can not find license contents. So am I allowed to run WebSphere Liberty on two CPUs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not state a CPU limit, so yes you can run it on multiple CPUs - do keep in mind that the 2GB heap limit is the total heap for all instances in an organisation - if you run multiple instances of Liberty for production their combined heap cannot exceed 2GB under this license.

Answer (score 3):

The license can be viewed on the download page here: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/runtimes-8.5.5-wlp-javaee7. There's a "view license" link on the right of the page.

The "Program-unique Terms" section which includes the 2GB heap limit across all instances is at the end of the document. You'll need to read the license carefully yourself.

Comment: Thanks. There is only one sentence about my case. "When not used on a Developer Machine or Build Server, Licensee may use the Program for a combined total of 2 Gigabytes of JVM heap space across all instances." The other part is about using it in development. So it seems that license says nothing about CPUs.

Comment: We do not state a CPU limit, so yes you can run it on multiple CPUs - do keep in mind that the 2GB heap limit is the total heap for all instances in an organisation - if you run multiple instances of Liberty for production their combined heap cannot exceed 2GB under this license.

Comment: @ThomasBanks Thanks, you can state that as answer.